# How to modify shopping-cart.tpl file to disable ajax-style cart site and add simple update button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

I'm trying to modify shopping-cart.tpl file and disalbe ajax-style quantity buttons. I want to have an option to modify quantity of products in carts, but in old-fashioned style (with input fields for quantity and "update cart" button). Now it gets JSON data on every change of quantity.

I'm using Prestashop 1.4.9 with New Prestashop Theme.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Modules > Modules
2. Search for "Cart Block"
3. Click "Configure"
4. Disable "AJAX Cart"